# IF EMPTY pulling from XML DE

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, xml

I am attempting to embed this script inside email body but getting an error when looking for empty tax data. I am interested to populate the word "FREE" from `@EstimatedFreightAmount` if no data exists in the XML.

On top of email:

```
SET @EstimatedFreightAmount = Field(Row(BuildRowsetFromXml(@xmldata, "//Order", 1), 1), 'EstimatedFreightAmount_att')
```

inside email body:

```
%%=Format(Field(Row(BuildRowsetFromXml(@xmldata,"//Order", 1), 1),'EstimatedFreightAmount_att'),"$#,#.00;-$#,#.00")=%%

 %%[if @EstimatedFreightAmount == "" then]%%
   @EstimatedFreightAmount = "FREE"
 %%[endif]%%
```

Error:

> There is an error in your email. Please contact your customer service
>   representative. Error 1: Script IF Statement Invalid
> The script
>   condition contains an invalid comparison operator. Condition:
>   @EstimatedFreightAmount ="" 
> Invalid Content: 
> if
>   @EstimatedFreightAmount ="" then]%%--> @EstimatedFreightAmount =
>   "FREE"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I would wrap your XML part inside of a indexof conditional to ensure that the appropriate node exists before running the BuildRowsetFromXML:

```
%%[ IF IndexOf(@xmldata,'<Order') > 0 AND Indexof(@xmldata,'</Order>') > 0 THEN
      SET @EstimatedFreightAmount = Field(Row(BuildRowsetFromXml(@xmldata, "//Order", 1), 1), 'EstimatedFreightAmount_att')

   ENDIF ]%%
```

This will help remove the possibility of that node not existing and causing errors in your code.

Inside the body, I would adjust your code to:

```
if NOT EMPTY(@EstimatedFreightAmount) AND @EstimatedFreightAmount != "FREE" then]%%

  %%=Format(@EstimatedFreightAmount,"$#,#.00;-$#,#.00")=%%

%%[ else
    SET @EstimatedFreightAmount = "FREE"
]%%

  %%=v(@EstomatedFreightAmount)=%%

%%[endif]%%
```

This will then output 'FREE' if empty or @EstimatedFreightAmount is already set to Free. And if not, then it will display the formatted amount.

Comment: Thanks Gortonington - I was able to inject your body code below and it pulled well. I had the indexof already inserted inside the products ordered. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Here's another working solution.

```
%%[

SET @EstimatedFreightAmount = Replace(Trim(Field(Row(BuildRowsetFromXml(@xmldata, "//Order", 1), 1), 'EstimatedFreightAmount_att')),"-","") 

If Empty(@EstimatedFreightAmount) Then 
  SET @EstimatedFreightAmount = "FREE" 
EndIf 

]%%
```